# Precision issues due to aggregation on double values

Tags: java, double, precision

I have a set of double values.
Now i have aggregated these value after every fixed interval and then computed the grand aggregation from those sub-aggregation.

For example: there are 1000 values initially and i am aggregating it after every 5 values. And then computed grand aggregates for all the values.

Now due to some reason i have to aggregate those values again with different interval(say 10).

Now when i compare both the grand aggregates to validate my result, i am getting difference in the value.

We have tried rounding off the value and then use it but it is not working always.

Can someone suggest me how can we handle this.

I have also attached sample code related to this problem.

Note: we don't want to use BigDecimal instead of double.

```
public static boolean generateNumbersAndAggregate(int totalIterations)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int accumulateAtN1 = rnd.nextInt(1000)+1;
    int accumulateAtN2 = rnd.nextInt(100)+1;
    int j =1;
    ArrayList<Double> valuesAtN1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> valuesAtN2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double sumAtN1 = 0;
    double sumAtN2 = 0;
    int totalRecords = 500000 /** (rnd.nextInt(1000) + 1)*/;

    System.out.println("totalRecords=" + totalRecords + "  accumulateAtN1=" + accumulateAtN1 + "  accumulateAtN2=" + accumulateAtN2);

    double finalEpsilon = 0;

    while(j < totalRecords)
    {
        double randomDouble = rnd.nextDouble();
        int randomInt = rnd.nextInt(100000);

        /*double d1 = rnd.nextLong();
        double d2 = rnd.nextLong() + 1;*/

        double randomNumber = randomDouble * randomInt;

        finalEpsilon += Math.ulp(randomNumber);

        sumAtN1 += randomNumber;
        sumAtN2 += randomNumber;
        if(j%accumulateAtN1==0)
        {
            valuesAtN1.add(sumAtN1);
            sumAtN1 =0;
        }
        if(j%accumulateAtN2==0)
        {
            valuesAtN2.add(sumAtN2);
            sumAtN2 =0;
        }
        j++;
    }

    if(sumAtN1 > 0)
    {
        valuesAtN1.add(sumAtN1);
    }
    if(sumAtN2 > 0)
    {
        valuesAtN2.add(sumAtN2);
    }

    System.out.println("List Sizes= " + valuesAtN1.size() + "   " + valuesAtN2.size() + "\nRawEpsilon=" + finalEpsilon );

    sumAtN1 =0;
    double list1Epsilon = 0;
    for(double d : valuesAtN1)
    {
        sumAtN1 += d;
        list1Epsilon += Math.ulp(d);
    }
    System.out.println("List1 Eps=" + list1Epsilon );

    sumAtN2 =0;
    double list2Epsilon = 0;
    for(double d : valuesAtN2)
    {
        sumAtN2 += d;
        list2Epsilon += Math.ulp(d);
    }
    System.out.println("List2 Eps=" + list2Epsilon );

    System.out.println("Value1="+sumAtN1+"\nAbsDiff=" + Math.abs(sumAtN1 - sumAtN2) + "\nSumEpsilon=" + Math.ulp(sumAtN2) );

    double mm = list1Epsilon+list2Epsilon+finalEpsilon;

    System.out.println("TotalEpsilon="+mm);

    return isEqual(sumAtN1, sumAtN2, 2, null);
}

public static boolean isEqual(double N1, double N2, double maxDiffAllowed, JobContext context)
{
    if(N1==N2)
    {
        return true;
    }

    long n1 = Math.round(N1);
    long n2 = Math.round(N2);
    if(n1==n2)
    {
        return true;
    }

    double diff = Math.abs(N1-N2);
    double ulp = Math.ulp(N1);
    double finalthresholdval = Math.max(maxDiffAllowed, ulp);
    if(diff <= finalthresholdval)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: "we don't want to use BigDecimal instead of double." - why? That would probably the best, easiest and most robust solution to get rid of the precision issues. Alternatively it might be possible to convert your numbers to a `long` that represents the smallest possible unit (the highest precision you need) and do integer math only - I didn't thoroughly read your code though so that might not be possible.

Comment: You can reduce the rounding error by using a more sophisticated summation algorithm, such as [Kahan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). You cannot completely eliminate it so consider testing for a range rather than a single value.